# Angular CLI: Can't load CDN Scripts in HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, cdn, angular-cli

Currently doing my first project with the Angular CLI, and I'm running into a ridiculous issue. For some strange reason, my scripts won't load when I load them from the  through CDN's.

Just before the  tag I'm loading the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

However, when I run *ng serve*, both these scripts aren't loaded. 
This leaves me asking: why? Especially since in my , I am loading the Bootstrap CSS through a CDN without any issues:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Why does the Angular CLI decide not to load my scripts? And does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Final note: I'm aware that I could *npm install* both dependencies and put them in the *angular-cli.json* file. However, I do not want to do this as I prefer to load them through CDN's. So I'm praying for a simple solution through the  tags!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error, if so what is the error? Additionally, if you're using Angular 2, I would strongly advise against using jquery, they are not designed to work together, and will likely cause more frustration than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "aren't loaded"? you not see them in the browser?

i guess that you have compile error, maybe you need to install [type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)?

Comment: I don't see them in the browser, and in the network log of Chrome I see that they're never pulled from their CDN's. They just don't exist on the webpage, for some reason.

Additionally: No compiling errors anywhere. I'll have a look at type, but not sure if that's the problem.

Thanks for your reply! :)

Comment: Can you check if the lines exist in the index.html in the browser?